# Comportamento Estranho no EntityFramework com StoredProcedure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Estou realizando uma busca através de `StoredProcedures` no `EntityFramework` e o campo de `Data` esta apresentando **erro** de conversão ao tipo `String`.

***Método***

```
public IEnumerable GetFilteredList(ConsultaBanner filtro)
{

    string sql = "spAdmin_Banner_ConsultaBannerPeloFiltro @titulo={0},"
    sql += "@apresentaCookie={1}";
    sql += ",@vigenciaInicial={2},@vigenciaFinal={3},@tipoSistema={4}";
    return context.Banners.SqlQuery(sql
        , filtro.titulo// != null ? filtro.titulo : null
        ,filtro.apresentaCookie //!= null ? filtro.apresentaCookie : null
        ,filtro.vigenciaInicial.ToString() //!= null ? filtro.vigenciaInicial : null
        , filtro.vigenciaFinal.ToString() //!= null ? filtro.vigenciaFinal : null
        ,filtro.tipoSistema //!= null ? filtro.tipoSistema : null
        ).ToList();
}
```

Esse código acima funcionou sem o erro de `convert`, porém não retornou nada então fiz alguns testes no `SQL Server` e percebi que os campos tadas estavam sendo passados como `''`, então alterei a `StoredProcedure` para converter `''` para `null` e o **erro** de conversão voltou a acontecer.

***StoredProcedure***

```
alter  PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAdmin_Banner_ConsultaBannerPeloFiltro]
     @titulo as varchar(100) = null    
    ,@apresentaCookie as bit = null    
    ,@vigenciaInicial as datetime = null    
    ,@vigenciaFinal as datetime = null    
    ,@tipoSistema as tinyint = null
as    
if(@vigenciaInicial='')
begin
    set @vigenciaInicial=null;
end    
if(@vigenciaFinal='')
begin
    set @vigenciaFinal=null;
end

select      
     id ,titulo,mensagem,apresentaCookie    
    ,convert(varchar(10), vigenciaInicial, 103) [vigenciaInicial]    
    ,convert(varchar(10), vigenciaFinal, 103) [vigenciaFinal]    
    ,tipoSistema [tipoSistemaId]    
    ,case when tipoSistema = 1 then 'Prestador' 
      when tipoSistema = 2 then 'Cliente' when tipoSistema = 3 
      then 'Login' end [tipoSistema]    
from banner    
where 0 = 0     
and ( (titulo like '%' + @titulo + '%' and @titulo is not null) 
or @titulo is null)    
and ( (apresentaCookie = @apresentaCookie and @apresentaCookie is not null) 
or @apresentaCookie is null)

and ( ((vigenciaInicial >= @vigenciaInicial and vigenciaFinal <= @vigenciaFinal) 
and (@vigenciaInicial is not null and @vigenciaFinal is not null )) 
or (@vigenciaInicial is null or @vigenciaFinal is null) )    
and ( (tipoSistema = @tipoSistema and @tipoSistema is not null) 
or @tipoSistema is null)
```

***Alguém já passou por esse problema***?

O ***erro***:

> The 'vigenciaInicial' property on 'Banner' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.

**UPDATE**

Ambas as chamadas abaixo retornam valor apos o tratamento de ''

> `exec spAdmin_Banner_ConsultaBannerPeloFiltro @titulo = null,@apresentaCookie = null,@vigenciaInicial = null,@vigenciaFinal = null,@tipoSistema = null`

ou

> `exec spAdmin_Banner_ConsultaBannerPeloFiltro @titulo = null,@apresentaCookie = null,@vigenciaInicial = '',@vigenciaFinal = '',@tipoSistema = null`

**Script Tabela**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Usuario](
    [Usuarioid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CpfCnpJ] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Nome] [varchar](120) NOT NULL,
    [sexo] [char](1) NULL,
    [DataNascimento] [datetime] NULL,
    [senhaAcesso] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [lembreteSenha] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [ativo] [bit] NULL,
    [DataCadastro] [datetime] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Usuarioid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Sua procedure continua não retornando nada, o erro é que agora ao invés de `vazio` ('') ela está retornando `null` e IEnumerable não pode ser null.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann você fala dos valores ou do resultado mesmo? Quando eu tiro o tratamendo de '' da procedure ela funciona sem aprensetar nenhum retorno. Quando eu adiciono o tratamento o erro ocorre.

Comment: Falo do retorno da procedure, pelo que entendi agora ela está retornando NULL, como seu método espera o retorno de um IEnumerable ele da erro. Se realmente for isso que está ocorrendo altere para quando não houver dados, retornar vazio e não null.

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann adicionei 2 exemplos de chamada da procedure e ambas retornam valor via SQL.

Comment: Você ainda continua com oproblema?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não consegui utilziar a procedure então converti a query pra linq

Comment: Deu errado porque os parâmetros tem que ter tipo

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tentei utilizar o SqlParameter e também não deu certo.

Comment: Vou fazer um exemplo mínimo

Comment: Se pode fornece o script dessa tabela?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não tenho aqui agora, amanhã eu posto o script da tabela.

Comment: E ai conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentei de diversas maneiras utilizar a procedure conforme o codigo informado por mim na consulta e pelo Virgilio. Acabei por converter a consulta para Linq to SQL

```
 public IEnumerable GetFilteredList(ConsultaBanner filtro)
        {

            return context.Banners.Where(b =>
                (b.titulo.Contains(filtro.titulo) | filtro.titulo == null) &
                (b.apresentaCookie == filtro.apresentaCookie | filtro.apresentaCookie == null) &
                (b.vigenciaInicial >= filtro.vigenciaInicial | filtro.vigenciaInicial == null) &
                (b.vigenciaFinal <= filtro.vigenciaFinal | filtro.vigenciaFinal == null) &
                (b.tipoSistema == filtro.tipoSistema | filtro.tipoSistema == null))
                .ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Tem alguns problemas um deles é na [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) da sua `StoredProcedure` tem que remover as duas conversões (`convert(varchar(10)`) ficando com esse nova [sql](/questions/tagged/sql):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAdmin_Banner_ConsultaBannerPeloFiltro]
    @titulo as varchar(100) = null,
    @apresentaCookie as bit = null,
    @vigenciaInicial as datetime = null,
    @vigenciaFinal as datetime = null,
    @tipoSistema as tinyint = null
as

select
     id
    ,titulo
    ,mensagem
    ,apresentaCookie
    ,[vigenciaInicial]
    ,[vigenciaFinal]
    ,tipoSistema [tipoSistemaId]
    ,case when tipoSistema = 1 then 'Prestador' when tipoSistema = 2 then 'Cliente' 
    when tipoSistema = 3 then 'Login' end [tipoSistema]
from banner
where 0 = 0 and ( (titulo like '%' + @titulo + '%' and @titulo is not null)
or @titulo is null)
and ( (apresentaCookie = @apresentaCookie and @apresentaCookie is not null) 
or @apresentaCookie is null)
and ( ((vigenciaInicial >= @vigenciaInicial and vigenciaFinal <= @vigenciaFinal) 
and (@vigenciaInicial is not null and @vigenciaFinal is not null )) 
or (@vigenciaInicial is null or @vigenciaFinal is null) )
and ( (tipoSistema = @tipoSistema and @tipoSistema is not null) 
or @tipoSistema is null)
```

<sub>**Observação:** a sua `SQL` está confusa, mas, mesmo assim funciona dê uma olhada a fundo se é esse mesmo o resultado que deseja.</sub>

O outro ponto seria no método, precisa ser configurado com os tipos e passados os dados corretamente se forem nulos (`DBNull.Value`) e com as modificações abaixo traz os resultados da sua tabela corretamente:

```
public class ConsultaBanner
{
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public bool? ApresentaCookie { get; set; }
    public DateTime? VigenciaInicial { get; set; }
    public DateTime? VigenciaFinal { get; set; }
    public short? TipoSistema { get; set; }                
}
```

---

```
public IEnumerable GetFilteredList(ConsultaBanner filtro)
{

   SqlParameter pTitulo = new SqlParameter("@titulo",SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);            
   SqlParameter pApresentaCookie = new SqlParameter("@apresentaCookie",SqlDbType.Bit);
   SqlParameter pVigenciaInicial = new SqlParameter("@vigenciaInicial",SqlDbType.DateTime);
   SqlParameter pVigenciaFinal = new SqlParameter("@vigenciaFinal",SqlDbType.DateTime);
   SqlParameter pTipoSistema = new SqlParameter("@tipoSistema",SqlDbType.TinyInt);

   pTitulo.Value = (object)filtro.Titulo ?? DBNull.Value; 
   pApresentaCookie.Value = (object)filtro.ApresentaCookie ?? DBNull.Value;
   pVigenciaInicial.Value = (object)filtro.VigenciaInicial ?? DBNull.Value;
   pVigenciaFinal.Value = (object)filtro.VigenciaFinal ?? DBNull.Value;
   pTipoSistema.Value = (object)filtro.TipoSistema ?? DBNull.Value;

   String sql = "exec spAdmin_Banner_ConsultaBannerPeloFiltro @titulo,";
   sql += "@apresentaCookie,@vigenciaInicial,@vigenciaFinal,@tipoSistema";

   return this.Banner.SqlQuery(
    sql,
    pTitulo,
    pApresentaCookie,
    pVigenciaInicial,
    pVigenciaFinal,
    pTipoSistema
   )
   .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Testei seu script e o erro persistiu. Eu resolvi meu problema convertendo a query pra linq.

Comment: O problema com certeza é no seu banco de dados que está mau configurado, esse código foi testado mas, a tabela foi adequada a ele! Não tem problema resolveu sua pergunta tudo bem @Krismorte